# Rollback update_attributes in before_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have the following model :

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :foo

    before_update :check_for_stuff

    def check_for_stuff
      # foo_was = 42; foo = 24
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if foo_was == 42
    end

    def update_foo
      update_attributes foo: 24
    end
end
```

The exception will be raised, but the rollback won't happen, the value will be set to 24.

How can I properly trigger the rollback of the whole transaction ?

Answer (score 1):

You could reset the value of foo if it was 42.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :foo

  before_update :check_for_stuff

  def check_for_stuff
    # foo_was = 42; foo = 24
    if foo_was == 42
      reset_attributes(["foo"]) # This resets just foo. Use reset_attributes to wipe all dirty changes.
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end

  def update_foo
    update_attributes foo: 24
  end
end
```

More information on `reset_attributes` and the ActiveModel::Dirty interface [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Comment: Edited my question, reset_attributes would do the trick but in reality I need the whole transaction rolled back.